# Java XML parsing of same name elements

Tags: java, xml, dom, java-io

I currently have an XML file for currency converter:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
  <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
  <gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
  </gesmes:Sender>
  <Cube>
    <Cube time="2019-09-17">
      <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1026"/>
      <Cube currency="JPY" rate="119.23"/>
      <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
      <Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.916"/>

    </Cube>
  </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

It is actually from this website: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Currently, I am trying to pull all the currency and rates as a key:value pair for a Map in Java, but I am having difficulty pulling the data as they are all Cube(?).

I tried to do something like

```
(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Cube").item(0).getTextContent());
```

where `eElement` is an Element for the NodeList.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at using xpath expressions instead of manually traversing the document elements?  It is cleaner and less code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I think xpath is a great way to do this. I have been trying to get some stuff to work, but it still does not print output. How would I be able to pull data? I have tried `xpath.compile("//Cube/Cube[@time=2019-09-17]/text()");` but that has not been working

Comment: @lee.edward01 Hi, have you come up with a solution since you've asked the question? I've stuck with the same problem while trying to parse the same ecb xml file.